# Reversible hex dump utility (aka `xxd`)

Tags: code-golf

`xxd` is a utility, bundled with `vim`, that has been used to encode answers to code golf problems on this site. It converts a binary file into a hex dump and back again.

Implement the `xxd` and `xxd -r` commands in the programming language(s) of your choice. Scoring is based on the character/byte lengths of a) your program(s) and b) any command line argument(s) necessary to switch a combined program between modes (they need not be `-r`). As in golf, lower scores are better.

- For two separate programs: *forward code* + *reverse code*
- For a combined program: *combined code* + sum(*forward arguments*) + sum(*reverse arguments*) - 2

### Specification of the chosen `xxd` subset

The forward command (*e.g.* `xxd`) accepts 0 ≤ *n* ≤ 2<sup>16</sup> bytes from standard input and generates ceil(*n* / 16) lines of standard output in the following format (all hex digits lowercase):

- Offset of the first encoded byte (format string `"%07x:"`); ends in `"0"`
- At most 16 hex-encoded bytes, grouped into pairs (format string `" %02x"` for even bytes, `"%02x"` for odd bytes) and right-padded with spaces to 42 characters
- The encoded bytes interpreted as ASCII characters, values not between 0x20 and 0x7e (`'\40'` and `'\176'`) inclusive becoming `"."`
- A newline (`"\n"`; `"\r\n"` allowed when standard output is in binary mode)

Minimal ungolfed C implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    unsigned char L[16];
    int t = 0, n, i, s;

    for (; (n = fread(L, 1, 16, stdin)); t += n) {
        printf("%07x:", t);
        s = 42;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            s -= printf(i & 1 ? "%02x" : " %02x", L[i]);
        printf("%*s", s, "");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            putchar(L[i] > '\37' && L[i] < '\177' ? L[i] : '.');
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The reverse command (*e.g.* `xxd -r`) accepts any unmodified output of the forward command (given a valid input to that command) and produces that original input.

### Example usage

```
$ xxd < /dev/null | wc -c
0
$ php -r 'echo join(range("\0",~"\0"));' | xxd
0000000: 0001 0203 0405 0607 0809 0a0b 0c0d 0e0f  ................
0000010: 1011 1213 1415 1617 1819 1a1b 1c1d 1e1f  ................
0000020: 2021 2223 2425 2627 2829 2a2b 2c2d 2e2f   !"#$%&'()*+,-./
0000030: 3031 3233 3435 3637 3839 3a3b 3c3d 3e3f  0123456789:;<=>?
0000040: 4041 4243 4445 4647 4849 4a4b 4c4d 4e4f  @ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
0000050: 5051 5253 5455 5657 5859 5a5b 5c5d 5e5f  PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
0000060: 6061 6263 6465 6667 6869 6a6b 6c6d 6e6f  `abcdefghijklmno
0000070: 7071 7273 7475 7677 7879 7a7b 7c7d 7e7f  pqrstuvwxyz{|}~.
0000080: 8081 8283 8485 8687 8889 8a8b 8c8d 8e8f  ................
0000090: 9091 9293 9495 9697 9899 9a9b 9c9d 9e9f  ................
00000a0: a0a1 a2a3 a4a5 a6a7 a8a9 aaab acad aeaf  ................
00000b0: b0b1 b2b3 b4b5 b6b7 b8b9 babb bcbd bebf  ................
00000c0: c0c1 c2c3 c4c5 c6c7 c8c9 cacb cccd cecf  ................
00000d0: d0d1 d2d3 d4d5 d6d7 d8d9 dadb dcdd dedf  ................
00000e0: e0e1 e2e3 e4e5 e6e7 e8e9 eaeb eced eeef  ................
00000f0: f0f1 f2f3 f4f5 f6f7 f8f9 fafb fcfd feff  ................
$ xxd <<< 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
0000000: 5468 6520 7175 6963 6b20 6272 6f77 6e20  The quick brown 
0000010: 666f 7820 6a75 6d70 7320 6f76 6572 2074  fox jumps over t
0000020: 6865 206c 617a 7920 646f 672e 0a         he lazy dog..
$ xxd <<< 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.' | xxd -r
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Comment: Should the reverse mode ignore incorrect ASCII characters? (FWIW the actual xxd does, which is quite useful).

Comment: @PeterTaylor: The reverse mode only has to work properly with *unmodified* hex dumps (start at 0000000, lowercase hex digits, 16 bytes on all lines but the last, no gaps, *etc.*), and input validation is not required. That said, it probably makes sense to ignore the 16-character "ASCII" column on the right, because it cannot be used to distinguish "." and non-printable characters.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, <s>122 + 54 = 176</s> 122 + 45 = 167

The forward script:

```
$/=$,;for(<>=~/.{1,16}/gs){$h="";$h.=sprintf"%*s%02x",++$m%2,"",ord for/./gs;
s/[^ -~]/./g;printf"%06x0:%-42s",$n++,$h;say}
```

And the reverse script:

```
/:(.+?)  /,print map{chr hex}$1=~/\w\w/gfor<>
```

(This one is interesting; there are all kinds of obscure bugs that can show up in the reverse script depending on the input, if you're not careful.)

Comment: Since `$1` is known only to contain hex digits and spaces, can you not use `/\w\w/` instead of `/[0-9a-f]{2}/`?

Comment: `$1` contains many things besides hex digits and spaces.

Comment: In the example, I only see hex digits and spaces between the `: ` and the `  `.

Comment: (Anyone know how to generate two monospace spaces in comment markdown?)

Comment: @Neil Never mind, I misread my own code. I don't recall now why I didn't just use `/\w\w/`. It seems so obvious that I feel like I must have had a reason, but I can't see one. My best guess is that it was a holdover from a version that was trying to avoid requiring the initial regex.

Comment: Fair enough, that would have made sense.

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript, <s>247 + 61 = 308</s> 225 + 63 = 288

*-20 or so thanks to ASCII-only*

Forward:

```js
b=>[...Array(b.length+15>>4)].map((_,i)=>(P=j=>i=>i.toString(x=16).padStart(j,0))(7)(i)+"0: "+(p=b.splice(0,x)).map(P(2)).join``.replace(/.{4}/g,"$& ").padEnd(42)+p.map(l=>String.fromCharCode(l>31&l<127?l:46)).join``).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBRa8IwEMff/RRZGHJHs9h2VYcsGSKDPQo@OpnRtpoS2xCDc4x99i6rbi@Dgzu4@//u7l@pkzpunbb@7vTQlqLdCLnknE@dUx@w4aaod34fJUMpM1zxg7IAb0yjkDAXlZA6BPfNwjtd7@AskhFyq/KFV85DxWJEGCNojGg8ITQCKzb8aI3eFhCzM2JHnEMaqqrR9XrNXWGNCu0B/8y@BjtGb/uEdtDnOocsxch2IiPkZSsvXXOY7ZWbNXkBRt4nffOYpOMnM8lGf9xr7q1bG0QeSljGLGHpCklE6GtNsffboC@FMQ0j740z@Q3t7vVA6eVYT4Qknm@vC6cewpP/IRcD02Hwo9TGhKFf84jGH4QOqvYb)

Reverse:

```js
d=>d.match(/[^:]{40}/g).join``.match(/\S\S/g).map(t=>+("0x"+t))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdRrc1RFEAbg7/6Kl0Vxl8BmpuceTeSqeAGVeGfB9EzPQEKyiWENKMJfj3MKVssq6tgfTp3qU/XUzLx95oDP@Fk53T9ZXT2L5237XLZ3ZH7Eq/Jkuvng0dbDl1a92nw8mx8c7y/39tZfFruL3aF7xCfT1fbOxnSiXkw2VrPZ@cnp/nI1bb3xtrbQHxqK8P81n88nM2xgslhOZu@9g7LRO/jiC3yjAlIh9LdAQ8@C9L/UnXp4eHwFz49PD@XCOPp2fcpAWeWgvApQUSUoVhmqKIGqqr1Z339qsXxj6K5opTU0aQNttYP2OkBHnaBZZ@iiBbrqMYW6QqpvgogMyJIDeQqgSAnElEGFBFRpUHBhMbn4/geXPpzOLm9cuTrfXDOmM0YZDUPGwFjjYLwJMNEkGDYZphiBqWZglCZjnQ8xbX308fbOJ2vFDqetrIYla2CtdbDehp6ATbBsM2yxAlvtoFy7fuPmrduffnbn8y@@/Oruva/XiuuKU07DkTNw1jk47wJcdAmOXYYrTuCqG5Rvvr2/@933P/z408@/PFgsHj76dc34znjlNTx5A2@HIfC@Rx99gmefh/wFvvqB2eNcpLbHT/YPnh4eLY/XSuhKUEEjUDAINjgE3wcoxJAQOGSEEgShhkE5@e302er3s@cv/vjz5V@vXv@TUuxKVFEjUjSINjpEHwNijAmRY0YsURBrHMs6dSWppJEoGSSbHJJPASmmhMQpI5UkSDWNKdwVVqzBxAZs2YE9B3DkBGbO4MICrjym5K5klTUyZYNss0P2OSDHnJA5Z@SSBbnmMaV0paiiUagYFFsc@n8aUGJJKFwySimCUsuYIl0RJRpCYiBWHMRLgERJEJYMKSKQKmNK7UpVVaNSNai2OlRfA2qsCZVrRi1VUGsdU1pXmmoajZpBs82h9csGLbaExi2jlSZotb1LmfTL8G8)

Might make an explanation at some point.

Answer (score 2):

### [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>222 + 108 = 330</s> <s>189 + 105 = 294</s></sup> 186 + 104 = 290 bytes

**Forward** (*-36 thanks to @[ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*):

```c
#define P printf(
t,n,s;main(i){for(char z[16];n=read(i=0,z,16);t+=n){P"%07x:",t);for(s=42;i<n;)s-=P" %02x"+i%2,z[i++]);for(i=!P"%*s",s,"");i<n;i++)P"%c",isprint(z[i])?z[i]:46);P"\n");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7BTsMwEETv/YrFKJJNXJRGVZFqLH4hB24lB@M47UK7LrYLIVW/PbjlMoeZeZqxc7s3tJ2m@871SA4aOAak1PNZkiSjOhgkjuLc@8DtzgQYN4tVq0gHZzqOupKjXKyESqUmcW5YUT0NayaTUFci6mWt8JmUiHPdMCiqemAlFrUcN1iW7X8L9V0GHyKTUTImbkBORTYtkxhvj3gmWvFy1fUyDzbsjXL3cpmm152DrxPaT3gP/oeg9wN8nA7HCP7bBUg53pvxFzq/fZz9AQ)

**Reverse** (*-4 thanks to @[ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*):

```c
b;main(a){for(char z[80];gets(z);)for(a=9;z[a]-32;a+=5)b=strtol(z+a,0,16),b=b>>8?ntohs(b):b,printf(&b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc5NboMwEAXgfU4xq8pWSGRMGEMs0kt0F2VhEwykBKfG6Q9Vz07tRp3dG837NPWmHtTYLouWV9WPRNFvYx2pO@VgPhbsJNvGT2Smksa9qko5H9Vpk3Gp1lVOdTV55@1A5rVKWJIiTXSlD4fiefS2m4ime53cXD96Q540lT/Lwh6zh3yHBWDOGYhU5IAlZoA6ROSCAxohAJsQ4aVr4O3e16@gnf0YYfUHpIFARAOiiB0VibMIWBajERjs4HAmdgDGfsLlfr1NYN8bB/5B8EgUmIcjrAFToUCUsb0LLAreAFPwP@GJQc1fcLbtdrv6BQ)

Answer (score 2):

## 253

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 200 bytes

```javascript
b=>{for(i=0,P=j=>i=>i.toString(16).padStart(j,0);t=b.slice(i,i+16),t+t;i+=16)print(P(7)(i)+': '+t.map(P(2)).join``.replace(/.{4}/g,"$& ").padEnd(42)+String.fromCharCode(...t.map(c=>c<32|c>126?46:c)))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNSwMxEIbv/ooYxE5ITLdrrdKalVIEj4UeVWy6H3WWdLOkQ0Vqf/uatl6EOQwz87wPTG13dpsHbOlm99BVpluZbF/5AGgSNTe1yTCWJr@ggM0aBiOhW1ssyAaCWiViQmaltw7zElChjHtFkiYoTWzbyBDM4V4ACtkbs54kvbFtHKVC6Npjs1zqULbORr6v98NDf6341TXjJ81zU8AwFfIs11Xwm9mnDTNflKC1PmflJssfb9OfPBuko6fhaJwLIQ7dBCp4TdRApe@CScbfGi4ujkP@UjrnFfvywRWXXG9bhwQ8Go9pxEzGSOd/milBEuP@BUxDsN@Q3sVXVOhcPDiR8KEYiiOOkeh@AQ)

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>57</s> 53 bytes

```javascript
d=>d.match(/(?<=:.*)\w\w(?=.{19})/g).map(t=>"0x"+t-0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdRrc5Q1FAfw936KP4uXfSjdJif3yrYKKqh4Ae@6Xk5yEiiWtpalRRC@es0zsDrOMI/nRSaTzPwmyT/JAz7jR@X04GS9fRYv2vJClnuyeMjrcn@@M9@/ttxdXBlW56vz@f5y8Uyn58POvaHPn8zXy72ZejLbWm@r4eLk9OBoPW/zmXpVu@iNhiL8fy0Wi9mALcxWR7PhjddQNnoHX3yBb1RAKoTeCzSOWZD@l7pVDw@Pr@L8@PRQLk2jr9anDJRVDsqrABVVgmKVoYoSqKray/X9p1ZHLw3dFa20hiZtoK120F4H6KgTNOsMXbRAVz2lUFdI9U0QkQFZciBPARQpgZgyqJCAKo0KLq1ml9986@135sOVravbi50NYzpjlNEwZAyMNQ7GmwATTYJhk2GKEZhqRkZpMtb5ENPuu9eWe/sbxY6nrayGJWtgrXWw3oaegE2wbDNssQJb7ai89/71Gx98@NHNWx9/8untzz7/YqO4rjjlNBw5A2edg/MuwEWX4NhluOIErrpR@fLO3a@@/ubb777/4cefVquff/l1w/jOeOU1PHkDb8dL4H2PPvoEzz6P@Qt89SPzG@citd27f/Dg98OHR8cbJXQlqKARKBgEGxyC7xcoxJAQOGSEEgShhlE5@eP00frx2fmTP58@@@v5i39Sil2JKmpEigbRRofoY0CMMSFyzIglCmKNU1mnriSVNBIlg2STQ/IpIMWUkDhlpJIEqaYphbvCijWY2IAtO7DnAI6cwMwZXFjAlaeU3JWsskambJBtdsg@B@SYEzLnjFyyINc8pZSuFFU0ChWDYotDf6cBJZaEwiWjlCIotUwp0hVRoiEkBmLFQbwESJQEYcmQIgKpMqXUrlRVNSpVg2qrQ/U1oMaaULlm1FIFtdYppXWlqabRqBk02xxa/2zQYkto3DJaaYJW2@uU2TBc/A0)

optimized from [Redwolf Programs's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215790/)