# Hex Dump your Source Code

Tags: code-golf, quine

When code-golfing there will be times where you need a Hex Dump of your code, usually because you've used unprintable characters. So, why not make a program that Hex Dumps itself?

### The Challenge

This challenge is to, given no input, output a Hex Dump of your source code in the following formatting:

```
0000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

Or, for example, if your program was `print("SomeString"):rep(123)`

```
0000: 70 72 69 6e 74 28 5c 22 53 6f 6d 65 53 74 72 69  print("SomeStrin
0010: 6e 67 5c 22 29 3a 72 65 70 28 31 32 33 29        g"):rep(123)
```

### Specifics

The hex dump is split into rows of three parts, each row representing 16 bytes of your source code.

The first part is the memory address. It specifies where the current row starts in your code. Written as a 2 Byte Hexadecimal number, followed by a `:`, then a space.

The Second, is the Hex Dump itself. This is 16 bytes of your Source Code, written in Hexadecimal form separated by spaces. This should be an accurate byte representation using your code's encoding.

Lastly, after a two space gap, is the code itself. This is simply 16 characters of your code, with Non printable characters written as `.`

### Notes

- This *is* a [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) challenge, so [Standard Quine Rules](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine) apply.
- And this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge too, so [Standard Loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- As shown in the second example, do not write bytes after EOF, instead use whitespace.
- Trailing whitespace is fine.
- Inbuilts to Hex dump, if you happen to have one in this specific format, are not banned but are frowned upon.
- Non printable characters refer to any character that, represented as only a single byte, cannot be represented as a single spaced glyph. For UTF-8, this means `0-31`, `128-255`. For the [Jelly Codepage](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), as all characters can be represented as a single spaced glyph, there are no Non printable characters.

Comment: related/duplicate? http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11985/47022

Comment: Personally I feel like this is an applied quine makes it different enough, but I'm willing to see the community's thoughts.

Comment: So for the record, you can't read your file name and `xxd` it?

Comment: Of course not, standard Quine rules disallow that

Comment: What exactly is an unprintable?

Comment: Depending on the chosen encoding, any Single Byte that is not represented by a single glyph, EG. `SOH`, `\n`, `\r` or, for ascii, anything >= 128.

Comment: For UTF-8, this is anything from 0-31, and 128-255

Comment: 1. I'm not sure I understand the purpose of the 8-bit encoding rule. If I can replicate the bytes of the file the interpreter received, why not let me? 2. Using only 2 bytes for the line offset unnecessarily excludes languages that require more than 65536 bytes for this task.

Comment: @Dennis what would you suggest is a good offset?

Comment: @Dennis I feel these are good points, so I will remove the encoding rule. However, I don't plan to remove the 2 byte line offset rule, as I don't, personally, want that to be dynamic. I feel it necessary to exclude languages that cannot achieve the task in under 65kb.

Comment: Personally, I'd leave it up to the answer. Excluding a language because of this is absolutely unnecessary in my opinion. If you insist on a fixed width, use something that should be enough for most languages. Most hexdump utilities use 7 hex-digits.

Comment: Also, you don't mention in your specs that there should be two spaces between the hexadecimal representation and the characters. You should also specify what exactly you mean by printable, this this varies by encoding.

Comment: Is ASCII 127 printable or nonprintable?

Comment: No, it is used as a control character for delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 39 bytes

```
ñi241"qp:%!xxd
Î4x
Íøø / &
f&3i ÿ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394Y6aYkYmhtFJhgZWqYkVFCtfhPpMKrsO9h3cc3qGgr6DGlaZmnKlweD/X//8A)

Note that normally V uses the latin1 encoding, where this is 36 bytes (which is what TIO says) but this submission is using UTF-8 where it is 39 bytes.

This is pretty much just a modification of the [V-quine template](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100426/31716) I wrote about.

Comment: Shouldn't the newline `0a` at the end of the output be removed?

Comment: @kritixilithos Ah, I forgot about that. It's easier to just add a newline to the end.

Answer (score 8):

## Perl, 81 bytes

```perl
#!perl -l
$_=q($%+=print"00$%0: @{[unpack'(H2)*']}  $_"for"\$_=q($_);eval"=~/.{16}/g);eval
```

Counting the shebang as one. Having the code length be a multiple of 16 saves quite a bit on formatting. Using `eval` to reassign `$_` to itself borrowed from [ais523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107027/4098).

**Output:**

```perl
0000: 24 5f 3d 71 28 24 25 2b 3d 70 72 69 6e 74 22 30  $_=q($%+=print"0
0010: 30 24 25 30 3a 20 40 7b 5b 75 6e 70 61 63 6b 27  0$%0: @{[unpack'
0020: 28 48 32 29 2a 27 5d 7d 20 20 24 5f 22 66 6f 72  (H2)*']}  $_"for
0030: 22 5c 24 5f 3d 71 28 24 5f 29 3b 65 76 61 6c 22  "\$_=q($_);eval"
0040: 3d 7e 2f 2e 7b 31 36 7d 2f 67 29 3b 65 76 61 6c  =~/.{16}/g);eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#@68Sb1uooaKqbVtQlJlXomRgoKJqYKXgUB1dmleQmJytruFhpKmlHluroKASr5SWX6QUA9ERr2mdWpaYo2Rbp69XbWhWq58OEfj//79uDgA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/) + xxd + cut, 61 bytes

```perl
$_=q(open F,"|xxd -g1|cut -c5-";print F"\$_=q($_);eval");eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#@68Sb1uokV@QmqfgpqNUU1GRoqCbbliTXFqioJtsqqtkXVCUmVei4KYUA1aoEq9pnVqWmKMEof7/BwA)

This is a universal quine constructor in Perl + a call to `xxd` and `cut` to do the hexdumping. None of the programs in question have a builtin to do a hexdump in the format in the question; however, `xxd -g1` comes very close and so it's possible to use `cut` to trim the output into the correct shape.

The universal quine constructor is `$_=q("\$_=q($_);eval");eval`, which creates a copy of its own source code in memory, and can be modified to perform arbitrary operations on it. In this case, I use `open "|"` and `print` to pipe the input into external programs, `xxd` which does the bulk of the hexdumping work and `cut` which changes it into the required format.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6) <s>229</s> <s>219</s> 162 bytes

*Thanks to @Neil for saving a lot of bytes*

### Note

Quite a few people think accessing the source code of a function the way I do it is cheating, but according to @Dennis, it's fine. As such, I'll leave my answer here.

### Code

```
f=_=>([...c=`f=`+f].map(d=>d.charCodeAt()[t=`toString`](16)).join‌​` `+` `.repeat(46)).match(/.{48}/g).map((s,i)=>`00${i[t](16)}0: `+s+c.substr(i*16,16)).join`\n`
```

### Usage

```
f()
```

Simply call the function with no arguments.

### Output

```
0000: 66 3d 5f 3d 3e 28 5b 2e 2e 2e 63 3d 60 66 3d 60 f=_=>([...c=`f=`
0010: 2b 66 5d 2e 6d 61 70 28 63 3d 3e 63 2e 63 68 61 +f].map(c=>c.cha
0020: 72 43 6f 64 65 41 74 28 29 5b 74 3d 60 74 6f 53 rCodeAt()[t=`toS
0030: 74 72 69 6e 67 60 5d 28 31 36 29 29 2e 6a 6f 69 tring`](16)).joi
0040: 6e 60 20 60 2b 60 20 60 2e 72 65 70 65 61 74 28 n` `+` `.repeat(
0050: 34 36 29 29 2e 6d 61 74 63 68 28 2f 2e 7b 34 38 46)).match(/.{48
0060: 7d 2f 67 29 2e 6d 61 70 28 28 73 2c 69 29 3d 3e }/g).map((s,i)=>
0070: 60 30 30 24 7b 69 5b 74 5d 28 31 36 29 7d 30 3a `00${i[t](16)}0:
0080: 20 60 2b 73 2b 63 2e 73 75 62 73 74 72 28 69 2a  `+s+c.substr(i*
0090: 31 36 2c 31 36 29 29 2e 6a 6f 69 6e 60 5c 6e 60 16,16)).join`\n`
```

Comment: (not sure that 'f='+f is allowed under standard quine rules but if it is then for 161 bytes I give you `f=_=>([...c=\`f=\`+f].map(c=>c.charCodeAt().toString(16)).join\` \`+\` \`.repeat(46)).match(/.{48}/g).map((s,i)=>\`00\`+i.toString(16)+\`0 \`+s+c.substr(i*16,16)).join\`\n\``.

Comment: Clever approach. I read some questions, and is appears people generally think it's considered cheating because I'm abusing a convenient language feature. I'll add that, along with your improved code, to my answer.

Comment: I think it is allowed, Dennis said on another quine challenge that using function source inspection is fine, and I know several "Golf a quine" answers use this.

Comment: Change the first `.toString` to `[t=toString]` and the second to `[t]` to save 3 bytes. Change the `<backtick>\n<backtick>` to `<backtick><newline><backtick>` to save another one.

Comment: Changing it the string method requires the function name to be a string, as such, it only saves one byte. As for the newline, it would result in an `a` in the hex dump, which needs a 0 prepended, and adding that check would only increase the bytecount.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>128</s> 112 bytes

```
eval b='7.times{|y|$><<"%04x:"%y*=16;c=("eval b="+(a=39.chr)+b+a)[y,16];c.chars{|x|$><<" %x"%x.ord};puts"  "+c}'
```

Without trailing newline.

Thanks primo for the idea of aligning to 16-byte boundary.

### Output

```
0000: 65 76 61 6c 20 62 3d 27 37 2e 74 69 6d 65 73 7b  eval b='7.times{
0010: 7c 79 7c 24 3e 3c 3c 22 25 30 34 78 3a 22 25 79  |y|$><<"%04x:"%y
0020: 2a 3d 31 36 3b 63 3d 28 22 65 76 61 6c 20 62 3d  *=16;c=("eval b=
0030: 22 2b 28 61 3d 33 39 2e 63 68 72 29 2b 62 2b 61  "+(a=39.chr)+b+a
0040: 29 5b 79 2c 31 36 5d 3b 63 2e 63 68 61 72 73 7b  )[y,16];c.chars{
0050: 7c 78 7c 24 3e 3c 3c 22 20 25 78 22 25 78 2e 6f  |x|$><<" %x"%x.o
0060: 72 64 7d 3b 70 75 74 73 22 20 20 22 2b 63 7d 27  rd};puts"  "+c}'
```